# Proper array structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

Commonly, arrays are formed like `var array = ["some","string","elements"]` or `var array = [1, 2, 3]`. Been searching for times, but I haven't seen articles that may clear my mind. Now, is it possible to have an array structure like `var array = [some, string, elements]`. As what can be observed, it was somehow a string without `""`.

To visualize my concern, I have this code

```
var data = []
for (var x = 0; x < arrayData.length; x++){ //arrData contains [1,2] structure
     data.push("$scope.item["arrayData[x]"]"); 
}
//which gives var data = ["$scope.item[1], $scope.item[2]"]
```

I needed that `var data` to form like `var data = [$scope.item[1],$scope.item[2]]`. Is it possible?

**EDIT**

My bad, I haven't explained my query fully. The `"$scope.item["` is a string, that's why I encapsulated it to `""`

**EDIT II**

Is it possible to have an array structure like `var array = [some, string, here]`. Consider that `some`,`string` and `here` are not variables.

Comment: `data.push($scope.item[arrayData[x]]);`

Comment: My bad, I haven't able to explain it clearly. That "$scope.item" is a static variable, more likely, it is a string.

Comment: Please update your question - click the `<>` button and provide a [mcve] instead of wasting our time. It looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Sounds like your wanting to `eval` the string then push the result of that into the array? Is that correct?

Comment: Can you explain your real use case? I sort of understand what you are trying to do but most of the time it does not have to be so complicated.

Comment: Say for example, I have this data `var array = "[$scope.item[1], $scope.item[2]"` which is not an array (a string). I am trying to ask if.. it is possible to form my var into `var array [$scope.item[1], $scope.item[2]]`. Like, converting string to array.... sort of.

Comment: Why are you having that kind of data in the first place? Are you writing a parser?

Answer (score 1):

Don't complecate it, Just go with using `JSON.stringify();`

Your code should be

```
data.push(JSON.stringify("$scope.item[" + arrayData[x] + "]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an array structure like `var array = [some, string, elements]`. There should be variables named `some`, `string` and `elements`.

`$scope` is a special variable in AngularJS. So, you should use it without `"`s. For example:

```
data.push($scope.item[arrayData[x]]);
```